# CORS preflight request not making call after the options request method

Tags: java, http, browser

I am trying to make a CORS call from my localhost to a website. The request headers is as shown in the image . According to preflight it first makes a OPTIONS type request and then it makes the actual call() to the server. I am able to get 200 for the OPTIONS type but it is not making the real call of GET to the server
[image]

Comment: It would be helpful if you would show the code that is trying to do the actual call.

Comment: the code is not too complex, I used HttpServletResponse  

res.sendRedirect(redirectUri);   

where redirectUri='www.google.com' or any other url

Answer (score 0):

The OPTIONS method will only tell you what the server allows you to do. If it fails from the browser after the OPTIONS method was a success then the Origin is probably the problem.

When you ask for the OPTIONS it will tell you which methods are allowed, but it will still check on the server if the Origin which the browser provides is allowed to perform those actions.